# [lua ]explain to me how this code work (nested loops)

Tags: loops, lua, nested-loops

```
    j = 5
for i = 1,5 do
for j = 2,5,4 do
print(i*j)
end
end
```

when output, I wondered a lot as to why it prints like that, despite trying a lot I still can't understand how it works. Please help me, if you can understand it.

Output: 2,4,6,8,10

Comment: Please tell us what output you expect, so we know what part is confusing to you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which part is confusing: the outer loop is executed 5 times assigning 1..5 to `i`, while the inner loop is executed only once each time assigning 2 to `j` (as the second iteration of that loop would assign 2+4 [as 4 is the step of the loop], which is larger than 5, so the loop is aborted), so you get `1*2`, `2*2`, `3*2`, `4*2`, and `5*2` printed.

The assignment of 5 to `j` outside of the loop is completely irrelevant, as the loop variable has its own scope, so any variable with the same name will be shadowed (not available, but with the value preserved) inside the loop.

Comment: i don't know, i follow here: https://www.educba.com/lua-loop/?source=leftnav

Comment: Is it more clear now after the explanation?